# What's the ideal way to configure an Eclipse Web Project to test Spring/JPA

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jpa

I recently used eclipse (myeclipse actually) to create a new Web Project via the new->web project wizard.  The default directory structure for the project looks as follows:

```
src
WebRoot
WebRoot/META-INF
WebRoot/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
WebRoot/WEB-INF
WebRoot/WEB-INF/lib
WebRoot/WEB-INF/classes (not visible via the Package/Project Explorer)
WebRoot/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

For jpa I added:

```
WebRoot/META-INF/persistence.xml
```

For spring I added:

```
WebRoot/META-INF/spring/spring-master.xml
```

When trying to run a very basic junit test to load the spring context and hibernate entity manager I was running into classpath problems. Initally to get around the first class path problem I encountered I added `WebRoot/META-INF/spring` to the junit->Run Configurations classpath when Spring couldn't find my spring configuration files.

But then I ran into another classpath error when jpa couldn't find my entity bean definition.  Reading [this article (dated 2007)](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2007/06/where-to-put-persistencexml-in-web-app.html) it states that `META-INF/persistence.xml` should be contained within `WEB-INF/classes` because JPA searches for entity bean class files in the parent directory of `META-INF/persistence.xml`

When I copied `META-INF` (via Windows Explorer since eclipse is hiding the classes directory) and all its contents into `WEB-INF/classes` my classpath errors went away (<strike>as well as the need to monkey with the junit run configuration to remedy the previous problem of spring not knowing where my spring config file is located</strike> turns out I still need to add the spring folder to the junit classpath option).

But now I have configuration files in a folder which does not show in Eclipse's Package/Project Explorer.

What is the best way to setup Eclipse for this situation?  Tell it to show the classes folder somehow?  Why does Eclipse create `META-INF` as a sibling to `WEB-INF` for web projects?

Is there a way to inform JPA to look for entity classes somewhere other than the default?

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know that eclipse mixes the compiled classes and resource from `src`  (and any other source code directory) in the `<WebRoot>/WEB-INF/classes` directory.

So one way to access the same file in Test and Webapp (for example META-INF/persistence.xml) is to put it in `src/META-INF/persistence.xml`. Then it is available in `<WebRoot>/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml` for the web app, and in `<classpath>/META-INF/persistence.xml` for EVERY application or test.

So my recommendation is to put all the stuff that is addressed via classpath (persistence.xml, spring.xml) in a source directory, and let eclipse do the rest. - If you specify the location of a resource via classpath, then it should work the same way for webapp, test, app.

*BTW: eclipse can create many source code directories, you can use one for the normal application classes, one for the class path relevant resource and one for the test classes.*

Comment: Thanks Ralph! I've typically just included my test classes in src with the application classes, just in a test package.  Question: Is there a reason eclipse's default Web Project structure defines a META-INF outside of a source code directory?

Comment: @new Thrall: I think you are talking about `WebContent\META-INF` - it is the META-INF directory for the WAR (containing signatures, MANIFEST.MF,...)